# Slim 3 post for every page with only one function

Tags: php, rest, routes, slim

I'm attempting to add a logout to each one of my pages when a `POST` request is sent. Currently my code is working but I have to define it for every route. Is there a way where I can have a `$app->post()` on my main routes file that will effect every page on my site?

For example, on my admin page I have to add this code just to get my logout working:

```
$app->post('/admin', function ($request, $response) {
    // Define POST data
    $params = $request->getParams();

    // Logout User
    if ($params['logout']) {
        // Logout
        User::logout();

        // Redirect to login page
        return $response->withHeader("Location", "/");
    }
});
```

Is there a way I can add this to a single file and every other page such as `site.com/admin` and `site.com/panel` will be able to access this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using middleware.

```
// Middleware to logout
$app->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
    // Define POST data
    $params = $request->getParams();

    // Logout User
    if ($params['logout']) {
        // Logout
        User::logout();

        // Redirect to login page
        return $response->withHeader("Location", "/");
    }

    // Return next middleware
    return $next($request, $response);
});
```

Comment: This time every Request with ?logout will you logout not only Post. Intentional?

Comment: @copynpaste The only way I'm going to get anything that has a value of `logout` is if the button to logout is pressed, therefore this works.